# Grouping the Split elements into own separate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, syntax, split

This is my data from .txt file:

> **S12*T0*0889*B*99*N1C0~**S12*T0*0880*B*99*N1C0~

this is my code which reads data from the .txt file:

```
{
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("2.txt"));
            String read = null;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            read = in.readLine();
            String[] splited = read.split("\\*+");
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");//Data Source Driver
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:testing");//Data Connection
            for (String part : splited){    
                    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into testing (d3)values('"+part+"')");//inserting data
                    System.out.println(part);//printing inserted data
                    System.out.println("inserted");//insertion confirmation
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
```

From my code i have been able to split the data between the "*" and store it in a array(splited).As a result in the database,only 1 column gets inserted.

The data between the "*" belong to separate columns in the database.

> Problem 1:
>   I need to separate data between "~" first and then separate the data between "*".
>   Problem 2:
>   i need to group the separated data into arrays so that i can insert into database later(every data has its own column in the database).
>
> Expected Output:In Database(ms-Access)

### |d1 |d2 |d3|d4| d5 |<--Columns

S12 |T0 |S12|B |99|N1C0|<--Inserted elements

Comment: You can consider tokenizing the string.

Comment: Show us exact expected output please

Comment: are you want to split first by`**` then `*`??

Comment: i've made edits so that the blank spaces are skipped.

Comment: shouldn't you first split by `~` to extract individual records and then split each one by `\*+`?

Comment: `S12 |T0 |0889|B |99|N1C0|` this or whatever you have mentioned??

Comment: @shyam you are right i need to first split by "~" and then by "*" .

Comment: @prashant,i have a text file with the repeating pattern(see the data).I need to insert it into database,but every data between the "*" needs to be inserted into a separate column(Expected Output is representation of database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding them in batches

```
public class Answer28535326 {

  private static void addRows(PreparedStatement ps, String line) throws SQLException {
    String[] records = line.split("~");
    for (String record : records) {
      String[] values = record.replaceAll("^\\*+", "").split("\\*+");
      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        ps.setString(i + 1, values[i]);
      }
      ps.addBatch();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");// Data Source Driver
    try ( Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:testing") ) {
      try ( PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into testing (d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") ) {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("2.txt"))) {
          String read = null;
          while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            read = in.readLine();
            addRows(ps, read);
          }
          ps.executeBatch();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: Explanation as requested

1. Original code was that it was inserting every column as a new row in
   the database. *The solution was to use a prepared statement with
   placeholders for **all** the column values of the table*
2. Since there were potential 1+ records per line added a method to 
   process multiple records per line and adding them as a batch

Comment: it worked!if possible can you write a small explanation about how you solved this.

Comment: This line in particular,may i know the regrex explanation"String[] values = record.replaceAll("^\\*+", "").split("\\*+");"

Comment: The `record.replaceAll("^\\*+", "")` is removing the record prefix `**` so that there is no empty token at index 0 when splitting with `.split("\\*+")`

Answer (score 0):

So something like this:

```
public class Answer28535326 {

private static String input = "**S12*T0*0889*B*99*N1C0~**S12*T0*0880*B*99*N1C0~";

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] records = input.split("~");
    for (String record : records)
    {
        System.out.println(record);
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(record, "*", false);

        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }       
}

}
```